# Actionmailer images sending in development not staging or production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

So I'm having an issue where images sent from the development server are getting displayed in emails, but when sent in production/staging mode the images aren't displayed in the email, however when copying the image url from the email source I can display the image in the browser. I have another app that's running with virtually the same production.rb file and it's sending the image without issue, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

#### development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  
  host = 'development.local'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'https' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'https://development.local'
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:                 587,
    domain:               "gmail.com",
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USER"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASS"],
    authentication:       :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '172.17.0.0/16'
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0'
end
```

#### staging.rb/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.force_ssl = true

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://production.local'

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  host = "production.local"
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'https://production.local'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'https' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USER"],
    :password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASS"],
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  
  }

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

#### views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;max-width:600px;margin:auto;border-radius:7px;box-sizing:border-box;box-shadow:0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);">
  <div style="overflow:hidden;background:#a1cbd6;color:#603914;padding:10px 20px;box-sizing: border-box;">
    <%= image_tag('logo_h.png', style: "float:left;") %> <h1 style="float:left;margin:15px 15px 5px;">Test Company</h1>
  </div>

  <div style="overflow:hidden;background:#fff;padding:25px;box-sizing: border-box;">
    <p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>

    <p>This account allows you to access everything you need</p>

    <p>Activate your account by clicking the link below:</p>

    <%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure its just not that whatever client you are viewing the emails in is blocking the images? Most do by default as this makes it easy for spammers to detect if the recipient has opened the email.

Comment: After messing with it last night it seems that it might be something to do with the asset path or something. I can load images from other sources without issue. I don't believe it's the client blocking, its the same on multiple mail clients and none are presenting with a "load remote content" button.

Comment: Does the email use absolute urls or just paths?

Comment: It's using absolute urls